# UISwipeGesture 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

If someone could please help me resolve this issue, would be great! I have spent a few hours trying to fix, with no luck

### Error...

> 2016-06-23 20:30:43.341057 Scaling Rings[408:38903] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
>   2016-06-23 20:30:43.750822 Scaling Rings[408:38776] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
>   2016-06-23 20:30:43.751531 Scaling Rings[408:38776] Metal API Validation Enabled
>   2016-06-23 20:30:48.293661 Scaling Rings[408:38776] -[Scaling_Rings.MenuScene slide:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145e1c410
>   2016-06-23 20:30:48.299061 Scaling Rings[408:38776] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Scaling_Rings.MenuScene slide:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145e1c410'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x190ad9980 0x1900d44bc 0x190ae0778 0x190add6e0 0x1909de61c 0x196e13754 0x196e16e5c 0x1969f6b3c 0x196894900 0x196e0747c 0x196e07100 0x196e06338 0x196892a24 0x1968638c8 0x19701efd4 0x19701941c 0x190a8a3f0 0x190a89cc8 0x190a87938 0x1909ba2e4 0x19239315c 0x1968ce6fc 0x1968c9438 0x1000a1d44 0x19055c600)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

### Code...

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

var startRing = SKShapeNode()

class MenuScene: SKScene {

    func slide(sender: AnyObject){
        debugPrint("WORKS")
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("slide:"))
        upSwipe.direction = .up
        view.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give us more details on the view (in didMove). It will need to be able to access the slide function

Comment: @Sam that is the entire GameScene.swift file currently, I am simply running a test project for future reference on the use of gestures

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your selector declaration to `#selector(slide)` and add an underscore before your method parameter `func slide(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)`:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    @objc func slide(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        print("WORKS")
    }
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(slide))
        upSwipe.direction = .up
        view.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

#### Swift 4.2

In the case bellow we use an argument to assign the target. This can only be done with a string

```
func createBtn(action:String) -> UIButton {
    let btn:UIButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: Selector(action), for: .touchUpInside)
    return btn
}
@objc func buttonTouched(_ sender:UIButton) {//The _ char is imp
    Swift.print("buttonTouched")
}
let btn = createButton(action:"buttonTouched:")//The : char is imp
```