# UIButton in table cell "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a button in a table cell, when pressed it crashes the app with the error:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9a39840a00
>   2016-11-25 15:32:04.310 App Name[19161:1264937] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[App_Name.routineCell forwardPress:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9a39840a00'

Here's the code:

```
   internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return routineGroups.count
}

func cellButtonPress() {
    print("works")
}
internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell:routineCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! routineCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = routineGroups[indexPath.row]

    cell.forwardButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.forwardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(routinesGroups.cellButtonPress), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

I looked at the solutions here: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004506/uiswipegesture-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance) and here [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344184/swift-3-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-xcode-8) but I get the same error every time.
The cell has its own .swift file where it was dragged as an outlet:
[Cell.swift file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jPwc.png)

When the crash happens Xcode takes me to the AppDelegate.swift and shows this: [crash goto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7yTU.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you use `forwardPress` in your app?

Comment: The `selector` method must be implemented in  class specified in `target`. `self` is the current class. Either implement the method in `routineCell`, then change the target or change the selector. Apart from that naming classes with starting lowercase letter is very confusing.

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov has a point - that error is not coming from the given code. Somewhere else, you must be calling `forwardPress:`.

Comment: @ganzogo i'm not calling forwardPress: anywhere in the code - the only place that appears is in the error

Comment: Is it possible it is called from one of your dependencies? If not, then I'm stumped.

Comment: @vadian - how do I move the method in routineCell - if I move it there it returns the 'unresolved identifier' error?

Comment: @ganzogo - which ones are my dependencies (sorry, I'm relatively new to this) -  "forwardPress" appears nowhere in any code I have written

Comment: Once again, the `target` must match the `selector`. If you move the method to `routineCell` you have to change the target.

Comment: @vadian - I think I tried the right thing - i moved the code and changed it to: cell.forwardButton.addTarget(routinesGroups, action: #selector(routinesGroups.cellButtonPress), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)   but still got the unresolved identifier error.  My knowledge isn't good enough to follow what you mean.

Comment: The confusion is `routineCell` once as a class and once as an instance. Name the **class** `RoutineCell` starting with a capital letter and then `cell.forwardButton.addTarget(routineCell, action: #selector(RoutineCell.cellButtonPress)`

Comment: I changed it to RoutineCell.swift and `class RoutineCell: UITableViewCell` but now it crashes even earlier when it tries to load the table itself.  Is the confusion in this line: ` let cell:routineCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! routineCell `      if so which one do I change?

Comment: The latter: `as! RoutineCell`. The name of the Swift file doesn't matter.

Comment: if I make that change, it accepts the routineCell thats the same as `class RoutineCell: UITableViewCell` this, but not the other one.  So its either `let cell:routineCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! routineCell` or with lower case routineCell class, or `let cell:RoutineCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! RoutineCell` with upper case, but if I use  `let cell:routineCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! RoutineCell` then it returns the error 'use of undeclared type'

Comment: Forget the type annotation, forget **always** type annotations unless the compiler asks you to use it: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for:indexPath) as! RoutineCell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the problem is about `forwardPress`, not `forwardButton` nor `cellButtonPress`. Did you check the Outlet Inspector in the Interface Builder?

On some interface element (maybe the cell when reading the debugger), you may have an outlet not linked in code called `forwardPress`. You perform the action on the element, IB looks for the `forwardPress` method, which does not exist => crash.

Comment: THIS ONE DID IT!!  I had checked the outlet inspector for the ViewController but not for the cell itself.

Answer (score -1):

For `UIButton` action in a `UITableViewCell`, you can use:

**Method-1** - Handle the button tap even in the `CustomTableViewCell` itself using **closure**.

`CustomTableViewCell` class:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var forwardButton: UIButton!
    var completionHandler : (()->())?

    @IBAction func cellButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        if let handler = self.completionHandler
        {
            handler()
        }
    }
}
```

`UITableViewDataSource` method:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.completionHandler = {[weak self] in self?.cellButtonPress()}
        return cell
    }
```

**Method-2** - Handle the button tap event at the controller level.

`UITableViewDataSource` method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.forwardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cellButtonPress), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
```